# /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: bad include path ~/.ssh/id_rsa.conf. /etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need help to solve this error, please

/etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: bad include path ~/.ssh/id_rsa.conf.
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options

Comment: Just what it says .. Bad include path on line 19 of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` --  You can correct this by finding the correct file and placing it on that line .. Most configurations read like: `Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf` for WSL

Answer (score 0):

The `Include` directives in the system-wide configurations must not begin with "~". It is acceptable in the user config only, so you should add that include line to the `.ssh/config` file in your home directory.